# Django - Is there any way to display multiple {% block content %} side by side?

Tags: python, html, css, django, listview

First of all, I'm new to Python/Django in general. The problem I'm facing right now has been itching me for the past day, can't figure out how to make this work.

So, I'm trying to create a grid layout (using Bootstrap 4) where I would be able to show Movies/Shows which I have completed watching. The closest I found was a blog tutorial in Python/Django, did help me setup everything, from logging in to creating posts.

Now, the website is like a typical blog - everything gets stacked vertically, until it reaches a certain amount of posts, then you see the pagination. What I would like to do, is to display some sort of grid, here's a small example of how it looks now, and what I am trying to create:

**`[ col-md-9 ][ col-md-3 ]`**

In the above example, the `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` fill in the `col-md-9` section of the site, almost like a `container-fluid`. Ignore the `col-md-3`, the blog had it as a sidebar, which I don't really need.

What I'm trying to do would need to look something like this:

**`[col-md-3][col-md-3][col-md-3][col-md-3]`**

Not sure how to make the `{% block content %}` smaller and make it float correctly, because I managed to make it float (kinda?) with the `display: -webkit-inline-box;`, but sadly, I can't seem to make all the elements of a specific size and position them correctly in the `[col-md-9]`.

I appreciate all the help that you guys can give,
Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: Jinja2 template block just provide a way to load html tags dynamically. This change needs to be done in your base definition block content's parent element something like `<div>{% block content%}...{% endblock %} </div>` over here div is your parent element (remember this needs be in your base template).

Comment: It loads the content without any problems. I want to have 3 or 4 smaller blocks instead of the 1 that fills the width of the `col-md-9`, while it still displays all the dynamic data (posts in this case).